Subset xts index based on date range ina shiny app
In the shiny app below Im trying to subset the xts object and therefore the plot based on date range but while the intial plot is created then I get Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2514).
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library("vctrs")
library("xts")
library('quantmod')
library('tseries')
library('forecast')
library('ggplot2')
library('reshape2')
library(stats)
library(forecast)
library(shinyWidgets)


ABT <- getSymbols(Symbols = "ABT", src = "yahoo", from = Sys.Date() - 20*365, 
                  to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)

# Select only Close price
ABT <- Cl(ABT)

ABV<- getSymbols(Symbols = "ABV", src = "yahoo", from = Sys.Date() - 20*365, 
                 to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)
ABV <- Cl(ABV)

SP500 <- getSymbols(Symbols = "^GSPC", src = "yahoo", from = Sys.Date() - 20*365, 
                    to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)
SP500<-Cl(SP500)
Dow_J <- getSymbols("^DJI", src = "yahoo", from = Sys.Date() - 20*365, 
                    to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)
Dow_J<-Cl(Dow_J)

# Assuming your xts object is named 'my_xts'
first_row_name <- index(ABT)[1]
last_row_name <- index(ABT)[nrow(ABT)]

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Share price prediction and movement"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Date range',
                   start = first_row_name , end = Sys.Date() 
    )
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             plotOutput("plot2")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  
  output$plot2<-renderPlot({
    spf_dw_data <- merge(SP500, Dow_J)
    spf_dw_data<-subset(spf_dw_data, index(spf_dw_data) >= input$dateRange[1] & index(spf_dw_data) <= input$dateRange[2])
    DateSJ <- index(spf_dw_data)
    
    ggplot(spf_dw_data, aes(x=DateSJ)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = SP500, color = "S&P 500"), size = 1) +
      geom_line(aes(y = Dow_J, color = "Dow Jones"), size = 1) +
      labs(title = "Stock Prices Over Time",
           y = "Adjusted Close Price",
           color = "Company") +
      theme_minimal()
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Don't be shy to use xts powerful native date filtering mechanism and remember that ggplot is meant to be used with data.frame objects... it will work with xts objects but there will be quirks. The version below should work in the way you expect
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library("vctrs")
library("xts")
library('quantmod')
library('tseries')
library('forecast')
library('ggplot2')
library('reshape2')
library(stats)
library(forecast)
library(shinyWidgets)


ABT <- getSymbols(Symbols = "ABT", src = "yahoo", from = Sys.Date() - 20*365, 
                  to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)

# Select only Close price
ABT <- Cl(ABT)

ABV<- getSymbols(Symbols = "ABV", src = "yahoo", from = Sys.Date() - 20*365, 
                 to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)
ABV <- Cl(ABV)

SP500 <- getSymbols(Symbols = "^GSPC", src = "yahoo", from = Sys.Date() - 20*365, 
                    to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)
SP500<-Cl(SP500)
Dow_J <- getSymbols("^DJI", src = "yahoo", from = Sys.Date() - 20*365, 
                    to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)
Dow_J<-Cl(Dow_J)

# Assuming your xts object is named 'my_xts'
first_row_name <- index(ABT)[1]
last_row_name <- index(ABT)[nrow(ABT)]

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Share price prediction and movement"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Date range',
                   start = first_row_name , end = Sys.Date() 
    )
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             plotOutput("plot2")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    spf_dw_data <- merge(SP500, Dow_J)
    date_filter_str <- sprintf('%s::%s', input$dateRange[ 1 ], input$dateRange[ 2 ])
    spf_dw_data <- spf_dw_data[ date_filter_str ]
    spf_dw_data_df <- as.data.frame(spf_dw_data)
    spf_dw_data_df$date <- rownames(spf_dw_data_df) |> as.Date()
    
    ggplot(spf_dw_data_df, aes(x = date)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = GSPC.Close, color = "S&P 500"), size = 1) +
      geom_line(aes(y = DJI.Close, color = "Dow Jones"), size = 1) +
      labs(title = "Stock Prices Over Time",
           y = "Adjusted Close Price",
           color = "Company") +
      theme_minimal()
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

